# Excel SEARCH function not returning expected results

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

Having trouble with the SEARCH function in Excel 2016.  I use it to find "JASN" in an array ("Description" F1:F17) and return the corresponding result ("Result" E1:E17).  That works.

However, if "JASN" does not exist, it evaluates to zero.  So I want to error catch this, using the SEARCH portion of formula.  The problem is, the SEARCH for the error catch is not treating the range as an array - yes, this formula is entered as an array, otherwise the 2nd SEARCH function wouldn't work.

[image: Sample data]

Sample data https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hybzTVQ9tdNPdyItDUf-hC5cZIMUrwJQ

Working formula with SEARCH

> {=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($F$1:$F$17)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17)))))}

Non-working formula to catch the error / zero result

> {=IF(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17)=0,"this sux",INDEX($E$1:$E$17,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($F$1:$F$17)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17)))))))}

Why does this formula not return the same result as the SEARCH in the 1st formula?

> {=SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17)}

Using the EVALUATE feature and stepping thru the first formula, SEARCH returns several `#value!` and one "1" -- which is correct.  In the shortened version, SEARCH returns "Description" from F1 and nothing else.  It does not evaluate the whole array from F1:F17.

Why am i getting different results using the same function (SEARCH) on the same range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SEARCH will return an array, but you need to do something with that array or it will only return the first result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17))))=0
```

Will return TRUE if `jasn` is not found anywhere in the array.

So:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17))))=0,"Not Found",INDEX($E$1:$E$17,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($F$1:$F$17)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17)))))))
```

---

But we can avoid repetition with AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E$,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($E$1:$E$17)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17))),1)),"Not Found")
```

and this can be entered normally

Comment: Why is the ROW divided by the ISNUMBER SEARCH?  Multiplication seems to give the same answer.
ROW($E$1:$E$17)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jasn",$F$1:$F$17))

Comment: False creates an error by dividing by 0. The aggregate ignores the errors

Comment: Multiplication seems to give the same answer.  Perhaps because it uses LARGE as a max?  A different function may not be so lucky?

Comment: Correct. If small it would return 0 so do the error and it will not matter